# Capturing invisible window with win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Trying to capture contents of windows using BitBlt. In this particular case, which is probably important, i am speaking of invisible windows/invisible areas on windows - invisible because of z-order, they are visible but covered with other windows. All i get is a black box.

```
HDC winDC = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
HDC hdc_offscreen = CreateCompatibleDC(winDC);

HBITMAP bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(winDC, areaWidth, areaHeight);
HGDIOBJ origHandle = SelectObject(hdc_offscreen, bmp);

BitBlt(hdc_offscreen, rect.left, rect.top, 
rect.right - rect.left, 
rect.bottom - rect.top, 
winDC, copy_from.left, copy_from.top, SRCCOPY);

// at this point i expect pixels to be there, but nah!

ReleaseDC(hwnd, winDC);

SelectObject(hdc_offscreen, origHandle);

DeleteDC(hdc_offscreen);
ReleaseDC(hWnd_main, winDC);
```

hwnd is the window i am trying to capture. Same things works like a charm with Aero theme enabled. I am using Windows 7 Professional.

Any idea what i am missing?

Comment: Didn't you ask this already, earlier today? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34988788/application-contents-not-being-captured-without-aero-theme-enabled  What happened to that question?

Comment: I deleted the question because of incorrect source code quote which i didn't know how to fix quickly.

Comment: You also posted an exact dupe to an earlier question of yours over the weekend. I'm concerned that you might be getting into the habit of asking the same question repeatedly if you don't get an answer immediately.

Comment: Your application of `BitBlt` is really .... weird. Anyhow : This function is not intended for image-capturing, at all. As the name sugests its main purpose is to do graphical operations on bitmaps. Notice how the documentation states _"Not all devices support the BitBlt function"_ - you might have a device which isnt even capable of `BitBlt` operations, you can check for that with `GetDeviceCaps`

Comment: No that is not a dupe. That is a completely different problem - the first one appeared to be unsolvable and i have given up on that one.

Comment: OK, maybe. What do i need to use then? PrintWindow()?

Comment: In fact, this is simply for screencapture application - to avoid capturing its own window

Comment: I meant the question you asked yesterday that was closed as a dupe that you deleted. That really was a dupe. You pasted the entire question verbatim. As for this question, why would a window paint anything if it's beneath another window? You just need to hide your window before you capture.

Comment: This is the most obvious but unfortunately not an acceptable solution, it has to happen many times a second and blinking on the screen will be untolerable...

Comment: I can see that would be undesirable. However, let me ask you again. Why would a window paint anything if it's beneath another window?

Comment: @specializt `BitBlt` is commonly used with screen scraping.  Display and memory DCs support `BitBlt` but not printer DCs.

Comment: Hes writing malware, thats why.

Comment: Invisible windows don't ***have*** anything to paint! You can't capture "nothing". This question makes no sense and has no answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet (though it's not guaranteed to work) is to ask the other window to paint itself to your DC by sending it [`WM_PRINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145216(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Hmm. Your answer *says* `WM_PAINT` (which is wrong), but you *link* to `WM_PRINT` (which is closer to right, although I'd have suggested `WM_PRINTCLIENT`).

Comment: @Cody Gray:  Thanks for catching the typo--that made it very misleading.  As for WM_PRINT v. WM_PRINTCLIENT, I thought the intent was to grab the entire window.  If it's just the client area, then WM_PRINTCLIENT is the first thing I would try.

Answer (score 0):

HDC returned by `GetWindowDC` just doesn't contain a window's image. I can imagine that this `HDC` refers to the same "bitmap" as other windows. When Aero enabled, they apparently doesn't share the same "bitmap" and that's why you get a good result.

I would rather try to force window to paint to your HDC instead of reading HDC returned by `GetWindowDC`. To get client area you can try to call `BeginPaint` with your HDC, but who knows what if a window will check whether it (or it's part) is visible or not?

To get non client area you could pass `WM_NCPAINT` with your HDC.

Standard controls support HDC passed with `WM_PAINT`. Other windows may support it, but it's not required. If I remember correctly `PrintWindow` relies on this behavior.

In general I would say that no a 100% way to get a window's image but `BeginPaint` and `WM_NCPAINT` should be a good point of start.